# Run openblas on multicore

Tags: multicore, openblas

I am implementing a simple version for matrix per matrix multiplication and matrix per vector multiplication with openblas with dgemm and dgemv. I see that openblas is only running on one core.

I tried adding the -lpthread for compilation but that did not make it work.

The way I am calling dgemm and dgemv is simple:

```
cblas_dgemv(order, trans, m, n, alpha, a, lda, x, incx, beta, y, incy);
cblas_dgemm(M, N, K, alpha, A, 1, M, B, 1, K, beta, C, 1, M);
```

Has anyone successfully run openblas on multiple cores?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the number of threads with [environment variables](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS#set-the-number-of-threads-with-environment-variables)?

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
```

if this does not work, you can set the number of threads openblas is using via the following function:

```
 void openblas_set_num_threads(int num_threads);
```

cf. https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS#set-the-number-of-threads-on-runtime